# Formula for tracking Wins&Losses from a specific Year and Sports

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

This is the formula I'm currently trying to use, however it only results in 0's.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((Log!$G$3:$G$1000 = "W") * ((Log!$J$3:$J$1000 = B2 & Log!$B$3:$B$1000 = A2)))),1 ,1)
```

- Log!$G$3:$G$1000 = Cells that are marked as W (for wins) and L (for losses).
- Log!$J$3:$J$1000 & B2 = Which year the match was in.
- Log!$B$3:$B$1000 & A2 = The sport.

If I remove the & Log!$B$3:$B$1000 = A2, the formula works just fine, but it's showing every result for every sport from every year, which isn't what I want.

I'm trying to get it to show only the wins from a specific sport for a specified year, but I can't get any formula to work.

Any idea?

Edit: I should have noted, this is for google's spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the filter function:

```
=FILTER(Log!A-Z,Log!G:G="W",Log!J:J=$B$2,Log!B:B=$A$2)
```

note I guessed at the first array for A-Z so you should modify to reflect the actual range your trying to pull in. Also there are always slight difference, so if it needs to be modified a bit, then please share a sheet with some dummy data